# Dynamic Related List - Single : Not auto populating parent value when click on New button

Tags: lightning

I have started using Dynamic Related List - Single. After I used this, in the related list, then clicked on the New button, the parent value did not auto-populating on its lookup value.

Is there a way to auto-populate parent value like normal related list.

On child objects, I have multiple record types. Also added conditions on component visibility.

Please help me.